# Neo4j + Postgres common transaction

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, neo4j, transactions

I have a Spring application which uses Neo4j graph database and Postgresql relational database. Both databases support transactions.

I have no problems in handling transactions separately on each database using Spring @Transactional annotation with proper transactionManager property.

However I have a plenty of methods manipulating data on neo4j db and postgres db at the same time. Such operations should be transactional so I would like to "merge" those separate transactions. I mean if smth fails on one database engine, then another one should also rollback his own transaction.

Is there any library or tool which can help me achieve that goal? Or do I have to implement it myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not want to implement this yourself. The protocol is called 2PC (Two-phase commit). Postgresql supports it; also Neo4j seems to support it.  You just need something to orchestrate the transactions between the two. Spring helps you there with implementations of transaction managers

Comment: This article explains how to use Spring JtaTransactionManager:  https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ChainedTransactionManager` just like below.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="com.springsource.open.db.ChainedTransactionManager">
  <property name="transactionManagers">
    <list>
      <!-- Postgresql Transaction Manager -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"/>
      <!-- Neo4J Transaction Manager -->
      <bean class="org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.TransactionManager"/>    
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: As I understand from description of ChainedTransactionManager, it does not implement 2PC. In this case, it can happen that transaction to Postgresql to commit and the transaction to Neo4J to be rollbacked.

Comment: I looked into the source code of ChainedTransactionManager. This is basically naive implementation of multi resource transaction. It just  handles transactions over a loop of provided transactionManagers. So there is no guaranty that commit will be made on both db engines. It's not the correct solution, however it's better than nothing. The way to go is JtaTransactionManager as @Cristian Sevescu said. Here is some info how to use it in SpringBoot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html